# Connect the docusign console through REST API in Apex

Tags: rest, docusignapi, apex

I have created an envelope, added recipients and documents to the envelope through REST API call in apex code. Now I want to view my envelope in docusign user interface before ot it sent to the signers. Can I connect to the docusign from REST API call in apex and view the envelope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [EnvelopeViews: createSender](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/) API (also called Embedded Sending) to open the "tag and send" view of the envelope and let your users send it through the DocuSign Console.  This also allows them to make changes to envelope before sending, given that they have the correct permissions.

This is what the API request typically looks like:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender
{
    "returnUrl": "https://your.app.com/callback"
}
```

Once the user is done sending the envelope they will be redirected to the URL that's provided in the `returnUrl` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

There are different type of views you can use, based on the Envelope status, details are available at https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/  You might be interested in seeing https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createCorrect/ or https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createEdit/ or if sender wants to see it then https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/